# How to send a file to Discord webhook in Rust?

Tags: rust, discord

I tried to send a file to the Discord webhook I've read [Webhook Resource](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook) and [Uploading Files](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#uploading-files) but I still can't get it to work. Here is what wrote based on the API document:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use reqwest::multipart;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    let part = multipart::Part::bytes(image.as_slice())
        .file_name("text.png")
        .mime_str("image/png")?;
    let form = multipart::Form::new()
        .text("Content-Disposition", "form-data")
        .part("files[0]", part);

    let res = client
        .post("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/6969696969/XD_XD_XD_XD_XD_XD_XD_XD")
        .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
        .query(&[("wait", "true")])
        .multipart(form)
        .send()
        .await?;

    println!("Response: {:#?}", res);
    Ok(())
}
```

The response status is 400 and I found out it means "Bad Request". How can I send a file?

Comment: The documentation doesn't indicate anywhere that webhook endpoints can receive file uploads. Do you have any documentation indicating that this is even supported?

Comment: @cdhowie yes it is supported I can do it with python discord library and also in ExecuteWebhook POST there is parameter files[n]

Comment: My guess is that the API wants more than just the file, e.g. it also wants a JSON payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with a crate called serenity

```rust
use anyhow::Result; // You don't really need to use anyhow Result you can just use Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
use serenity::{http::Http, model::webhook::Webhook};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let http = Http::new("token");

    let url = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/{id}/{token}";
    let webhook = Webhook::from_url(&http, url).await?;

    webhook
        .execute(&http, true, |w| {
            w.content("Test")
                .username("Test")
                .add_file("/path/to/file")
        })
        .await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't set `.header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")` because `.multipart()` function does that for you, same with `.text("Content-Disposition", "form-data")`